# URL displays strange characters

Tags: asp.net-4.5

I have recently upgraded my webserver to Win Server 2012 R2 using ASP.Net 4.5. I am pre-compiling using v4.0.30319.  While the site is running properly, the URL display is strange.  For example, instead of showing lucidequipment.com/default.aspx, it shows

http://lucidequipment.com/(S(tm0o0swulbgb32flcxqankuy))/default.aspx

What is causing all those other characters?

Answer (score 0):

That is how ASP.NET maintains cookie less session id's, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178582(v=vs.100).aspx.